# sum of amount group by condition optimise query

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization

I have a view consists of data from different tables. major fields are BillNo,ITEM_FEE,GroupNo. Actually I need to calculate the total discount by passing the groupNo. The discount calculation is based on the fraction of amount group by BillNo(single Bill no can have multiple entries). If there are multiple transactions for a single BillNo then discount is calculated if decimal part of sum of ITEM_FEE is greater than 0 and if there is only single transaction and the decimal part of ITEM_FEE is greater than 0 then the decimal part will be treated as discount. 
I have prepared script and I am getting total discount for a particular groupNo.

```
declare @GroupNo as nvarchar(100)
set @GroupNo='3051'

SELECT Sum(disc) Discount 
FROM   --sum(ITEM_FEE) TotalAmoiunt, 
(SELECT (SELECT CASE 
                  WHEN ( Sum(item_fee) )%1 > 0 THEN Sum(( item_fee )%1) 
                END 
         FROM   view_bi_sales VBS 
         WHERE  VBS.billno = VB.billno 
         GROUP  BY billno) Disc 
 FROM   view_bi_sales VB 
 WHERE  groupno = @GroupNo)temp
```

The problem is that it takes almost 2 minutes to get the result.

Please help me to find the result faster if possible.

Comment: with that much aggregation it is not surprising. Perhaps you should provide sample data and expected output so that we can variate your quert

Comment: Can you post the definition of your View `view_bi_sales`? I doubt the query you have above is the root problem , and it's more likely to be a a problems with the underlying View.

Comment: can you please provide some sample data and your expected output

Comment: Whats the point of doing `% 1` on the sum?

Comment: I feel like that correlated subquery would be better handled by a Windowed Aggregate function. Difficult to say for sure without sample data and results though.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson , to find if the sum has a decimal part greater than 0

Comment: Probably not relevant to the performance issue but why bother with the check, if it is 0 then it wont affect the outer sum anyway.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks alot, I got the answer without using case inside the subquery. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your help and support , as I was already calculating sum of decimal part of ITEM_FEE group by BillNo , there was no need of checking greater than 0 or not. below query gives me the desired ouput in less than 10 sec

```
  select  sum(discount) from
    (select  sum((ITEM_FEE)%1) discount from view_BI_Sales 
    where groupno=3051
    group by BillNo )temp
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you don't need a `JOIN`.  This might help performance:

```
SELECT SUM(disc) as Discount 
FROM (SELECT (CASE WHEN SUM(item_fee % 1) > 0
                   THEN SUM(item_fee % 1) 
             END) as disc
      FROM view_bi_sales VBS 
      WHERE groupno = @GroupNo
      GROUP BY billno
     ) vbs;
```